# Open a program into a specific KDE 'Activity'?

Tags: command-line, scripts, kde, activities-overview

Hopefully a simple enough question - using a shell script (unless there's something better for this?) to launch specific apps for specific tasks. I use activities pretty religiously (I have them bound to meta + media contoller keys and it's delicious), and I was hoping there was a way to get the programs to open into their relevant activity screens.

I've attempted to do my due diligence in looking for an answer elsewhere - sorry if it exists already I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a window rule: Right-click on the titlebar of a window of the program > More actions > Configure special application settings > Add property > Activities.

Comment: Such a great solution. I thought it would have some shortcomings with opening the same program with different projects to different activities, but was able to get around that with identifying a substring. I never would have thought of this approach, especially given I fully believed it would be a shell solution. Thanks a bunch!